# Importing AutoML edge train model in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, google-cloud-automl, automl

I trained an object detection model using AutoML Vision which was then exported as a '**saved_model.pb**' file. I can load and run this model using the following few lines of code:

```
import tensorflow as tf    
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
        tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, ['serve'], export_path)
        output = sess.run("detection_boxes:0", feed_dict= { INPUT_NODE : [<some_image_in_binary>]})
```

When I try to use OpenCV v4.1.2's function `cv::dnn::readNetFromTensorflow("saved_model.pb")` to load the same model, it breaks with the message:

```
[libprotobuf ERROR C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc14\opencv\3rdparty\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\wire_format_lite.cc:629] String field 'opencv_tensorflow.FunctionDef.Node.ret' contains invalid UTF-8 data when parsing a protocol buffer. Use the 'bytes' type if you intend to send raw bytes.
```

I've tried changing the occurrences of '*string*' to '*bytes*' in **saved_model.pb** after reading an answer somewhere. In this case, the code breaks with an unhandled exception.

Additionally, if I try to parase the file using `tf.gfile.FastGile()` it yields `google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message`

Here's the saved model - [Model](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k71lm1jcEOYo9ryrW7gz8HHgP2cP17OC/view?usp=sharing)

Any ideas on how to import this model in OpenCV?